# Convert from String to Base 64 String JSP

Tags: jsp, base64

I want to convert String of password to Base 64 before i input it to database, so it will be safer. Can i achieve that?
Here the example from C#.net :

> Byte[] enByte = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(thepassword);
>
> string lsPwd = Convert.ToBase64String(enByte);

Comment: It **definitely** won't be safer. The original password is still recoverable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried, and it's work, sorry to disturb you with my post :)

> DatatypeConverter dc = null;
>   byte[] decodedBytes = vpass.getBytes();
>   String pass = dc.printBase64Binary(decodedBytes);

Answer (score 1):

Converting it to Base64 isn't even remotely safe. Use a hashing approach, preferably with a [random salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

Comment: but i need to convert it back to recover password, so i will need 2 way function :) . Do you know how to convert String to Base 64 String in JSP?

Comment: Why do you need to recover the password?

Comment: when the user forget the password, i still can recover it

Comment: Give them a way to choose a new password.

Comment: but my job to convert from C# asp.net to JSP , there was 64 base String converter but i don't know how it will be in JSP :)

Comment: If someone asks how to stick their forks in their eyes without blinding themselves, I will advise, "Don't stick forks in your eyes." If they argue, "But it's part of my job description!" I will respond, "Stick forks in your eyes if you must. But you *will* go blind; I can't help you with that." If you are tasked with doing something as idiotic and irresponsible as storing user's passwords in a recoverable way, then it's up to you and your conscience to decide whether to follow orders or common sense, but I won't contribute to this madness.

Comment: just say you don't know how :)

Comment: @Nore: Speculatively projecting motives onto me may make you feel better, but it's pretty obvious that you are simply deflecting attention away from an ill-advised course of action.